# How do you implement quicksort with the pivot in the middle position and what is this variation called?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

How do you implement quicksort with the pivot in the middle position and not in the last/first one?

Comment: As Codor suggests, this is known as Broken Quicksort :) Specifically this does one partitioning of the input array - it generally does not sort it.

Comment: "Have I developed the iterative version of Quick Sort?" - no, recursive quicksort relies on the call stack to keep track of which parts of the sequence have already been sorted. You'd need your own stack-like structure to keep track of that in an iterative version. This is just the "partition" stage of a regular quicksort, missing recursive calls to sort the partitions.

Comment: Btw, no need to write swapItems, there is a (template) [std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) that is doing the same for all types.

Comment: Thx Mike for the stack suggestion, I will try it

Comment: If you google iterative quicksort, you will see that it already exists.

Comment: No wait, the more I read this...  This doesn't partition!  It just shuffles things about to a vaguely slightly more partitoined data.  It moves smaller values toward the front half and larger values toward the right half, but there's no guarantees of much else.  Note that the pivot value changes _every time you do a swap_

Comment: Hint: Giving `{0, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 2, 5, 8}` to your algorithm results in `0 7 4 1 2 6 3 5 8 9 ` with `2` as the last "pivot".  Hardly sorted, only vaguely partitioned.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cedef8d83fd461c  Next time you think you've invented a new thing, make sure it works?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The answer lies in the Wikipedia article linked in this post.

Comment: why not make use of `std::partition`? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/045c59d7f0113db3

Comment: Answering your own question and accepting that answer is explicitly allowed; there is even a badge for it. (I tried to be plain, sorry if I was/seem sarcastic.)

Comment: Your answer is getting down voted because your answer is not useful and is not informative. That means it is a poor answer. There was no need to post it. If you had posted "this is an incomplete implementation of quicksort", your answer would have been correct, and possibly have even earned upvotes if you were somewhat witty or charming in doing so.

Comment: Ok, I'll be more careful next time. Thx to everybody for the suggestions and feedback.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), as the function name suggests; however there apparently is no recursive call to sort the parts after pivoting. I suggest moving the output out of the function `quickSort` and add recursive calls to parts of the array after the poivoting and rearrangement.

Comment: Thx to everybody for the feedback. What happens if I move the left and right indexes increments inside the if{} blocks? Does it then partition the array correctly?

Comment: By the way this is no homework LOL, I just love algorithms... My aim is to partition the array with the pivot in the middle, and not use first/last element. By this way the worst case scenario running time is improved. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @GeneralDynamix, the Wikipedia article on Quicksort linked in this answer addresses this.

Comment: @Don Reba thx for the tip